# X-bar theory and Trees questions! Complement vs adjunct

Tags: syntax

I am having a X-bar theory test soon but unfortunately I don't got access for the answers for questions I did. Can anyone check and tell me if I'm doing right, because I'm confused with complement/adjunct when it comes to prepositional phrase.

PSR:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9g2L.jpg

My work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCpos.jpg

Question 1: 'his nose up in the air' is supposed to be an idiom, so is 'up in the air' still an adjunct?
Question 2: Are 'about the Avengers' and 'with no real substances' adjuncts?
Question 3: I don't know if 'about the outcome ........' is an adjunct. What about 'in France'?
Question 4: Is 'in fright' an adjunct?

Hopefully someone can tell me if I'm doing them right, and any mistake that I have made with my trees... Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's a [fright [with a night hag]]? Draw-my-homework-tree questions are discouraged here, being off-topic as defined in the [help centre](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help). You can modify your post to make it an appropriate question. Regarding your adjuncts, watch for your constituents to make sense, and use the optionality test.

Comment: You're also asking about too much at one time. Consider if you could ask individual questions based on small trees that contain not much more than exactly what is being asked about.